Do you know why my max function with an initializer list in c++ is throwing error: expected expression?
I'm trying to find the maximum of three variables and placed them in curly braces to make it an initializer list inside of the max() function.
I've used this method before and it should work on this new device I'm running VSCode on. I have clang installed, C/C++ extension in VSCode, and I'm not exactly sure how to check what version my c++ is.
I know I could just make it two max variables or use *max_element() if I turned it into a vector, but I just want to figure out why this isn't working.
Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string sc, m1, m2, m3, sp;

int main() {
    cout << "School Name: ";
    getline(cin, sc);
    cout << "Team Member 1: ";
    getline(cin, m1);
    cout << "Team Member 2: ";
    getline(cin, m2);
    cout << "Team Member 3: ";
    getline(cin, m3);
    cout << "Sponsor: ";
    getline(cin, sp);

    int max_l = max({m1.length(), m2.length(), m3.length()});
}

And the error:
1.cpp:19:21: error: expected expression
   19 |     int max_l = max({m1.length(), m2.length(), m3.length()});


cout << "C++ version is " << __cplusplus << "\n"; (Your code works on my machine.  I'm using C++17.)

When I ran this line, it printed 199711. Do you know how to change the version? (P.S. I'm on mac)

@Kaydan Apple's clang defaults to C++98. Specify a recent version when you compile, like -std=c++17 or something.

OT: You should include <string>.

C++23 is the current C++ standard so you could go with -std=c++23
